# Custom button to changing image after click

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I am a beginner at android app developing and I have few buttons in my page which i want to change the image with a click. However, eventhough i have labeled the buttons according to the order and used the id's to create the buttons in the oncreate method, when I test it doesnt change the image for the proper button. For example, if the code is written to trigger 2nd button, it triggers the 5th button. I hope my question is understandable. The code is below.

```
    public class StartGameActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine;
    int counter, onOff;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.game_start);

        one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.empty_button);
        two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.empty_button2);
        three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.empty_button3);
        four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.empty_button4);
        five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.empty_button5);
        six = (Button) findViewById(R.id.empty_button6);
        seven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.empty_button7);
        eight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.empty_button8);
        nine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.empty_button9);


        one.setOnClickListener(this);
        two.setOnClickListener(this);
        three.setOnClickListener(this);
        four.setOnClickListener(this);
        five.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v == one){

            v.setPressed(true);
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle);
                    }
                    else if(v == two){

        v.setPressed(true);
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle);
                    }
```

This is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView 
    android:contentDescription="@string/game_board"
    android:src="@drawable/gameboard2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/empty_button"
android:layout_width="75dp"
android:layout_height="75dp"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/empty_button3"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/empty_button3"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/empty_button4"
android:background="@drawable/customemptybutton" />


<Button
android:id="@+id/empty_button2"
android:layout_width="75dp"
android:layout_height="75dp"
android:layout_above="@+id/empty_button5"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/empty_button5"
android:background="@drawable/customemptybutton2"
android:gravity="center" />
```

it pretty much goes similarly for until the end

Comment: post your xml game_start

Answer (score 0):

Just read your comment.

Please post your xml, are you sure the id's assumed by the Java matches the XML?  Also, you don't need to setPressed() in the onClick().  Since all the buttons are sharing the same listener, I've seen practices like the following work better rather than holding references to all your buttons.

```
public void onClick(View v) { 

switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        // application logic
    case R.id.button2:
        //application logic
}

}
```

Comment: Yes I saw this method earlier. But my problem is this app I am making is multiplayer and I want to feature different images for different players. But in this case you can only press it to get one image which is not helpful to me. Sorry I could not write it down earlier but that is my final motive.

Comment: I posted xml and tried your method. If you look at my xml you can see that I have not put wrong id's in the code. But still java is not activating the correct button. I just tried it with three buttons. it gives me three different ones and not what I want.